# hooks on steak (behaviour driven development)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bdd, ruby-1.9.2

I want to use hooks in steak to prevent excessive repetition of code. Is there any way to use hooks as in steaks like in cucumber? Any help will be appreciated.